# How to diagnose one thread blocking another

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there some way to tell if/when two threads are competing to access the same memory location and causing a block?

Comment: for block you mean a deadlock?

Comment: No - a deadlock is permanent and will case a crash (which I don't have). I mean block which may just result in inefficiency.

Comment: why should a deadlock cause a crash

Comment: According to wikipedia "A deadlock is a situation in which two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does." - my program doesn't come to a halt. I am just trying to diagnose mystery slowness in my working program (like 30% slower than expected).